# Python Django List All Posts Belonging To One Category

Tags: python, django, listview, detailview

I want to list all posts belonging to one category using the python django framework.

I think the best way is to use django.views.generic.ListView

My Models:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('category-detail', kwargs=kwargs)    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.name
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My Url-Patterns:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('category/<str:slug>/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail')
]
```

My View:

```py
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 8
    template_name = 'blog/category_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category_id=Category.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).first().id).all()
```

This works for me. However it seems like it is not the most elegant way to do it, since I have to get the category_id first and then filter the posts.

Is there are more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do:

`posts = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).post_set.all()`

Assumes that the `slug` field is unique.

The docs describe going backwards well:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

With your `get_queryset()` method, it may be worth being a little more defensive with your use of kwargs:

```
def get_querset(self):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
    return category.post_set.all()
```

That way if a bad slug is passed into the url, it'll return a 404 instead of a `DoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: Silly me. That does work of course. Thank you very much